# hide HIGHLIGHTS presets from end user

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a way to hide this¹ from users?

[image: ORACLE APEX interactive report Highlight setting]

even though I like to use this very much, it's kind of irritating to have these tags at the top of the report.

**(1)** It's the thing that appears when you do ACTION/FORMAT/Highlight on an interactive report. It also gives user the ability to edit highlighting conditions, when they click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the element in the browser dev tools. Notice that the container div around the interactive report filters/formats has a class `a-IRR-controlsContainer`. With this info you can get to work.

Create a dynamic action:

- Event: After Refresh
- Event Scope: Dynamic (if you set this to static they will reappear on partial page refresh)

Add a true action:

- Action: Execute javascript code:
- Code:
  `$('.a-IRR-controlsContainer').hide()`
- Fire on initialization: true

Note that if you do this, it could be confusing to users because they can add a filter but no longer remove it (since that control is hidden...)

Comment: now I learnt how it's done. hartelijk bedankt @Koen